# Force Uppercase on Symfony2 form text field

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I've inherited a Symfony2 project that has a form built as such:

```
        $builder
        ->add('Status', 'choice', array(
          'choices' => array('' => '', 'PASS' => 'PASS', 'FAIL' => 'FAIL', 'INCOMPLETE' => 'INCOMPLETE', 'DROPPED' => 'DROPPED',),
          'required' => FALSE,
        ))
        ->add('First_Name', 'text', array('label'=>'First Name',
          'required' => FALSE))
        ->add('Last_Name', 'text', array('label'=>'Last Name',
          'required' => FALSE))
        ->add('PID', 'text', array('label'=>'License Number',
          'required' => FALSE))
       ;
```

I need to have any letters entered in the PID field to be forced to uppercase. However I cannot find a option/attribute/... to do this.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: I would really like to know why this question was down-voted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I’m not sure if you ask for server-side validation or assistance for client-side uppercase input. In case of the latter: you could add a CSS class or a `data-*` attribute (something like `->add('PID', 'text', ['label'=>'License Number', 'required' => FALSE, 'attr' => ['data-behavior' => 'uppercase']])`) to the PID element. Then, you could add a JavaScript event handler in the form (preferably using jQuery or some other framework) to automatically convert lowercase to uppercase letters on blur/change. (I would prefer the `data-*` attribute, as this has nothing to do with CSS.)

To enforce that on the server-side, you could use a `@Assert\Regex` annotation.

Answer (score 6):

If you use bootstrap this should work:

```
    $builder
           ->add('Status', 'choice', array( 'choices' => array('' => '',  'PASS' => 'PASS', 'FAIL' => 'FAIL', 'INCOMPLETE' => 'INCOMPLETE', 'DROPPED' => 'DROPPED',),
             'required' => FALSE,
             'attr' => array( 'class' => 'text-uppercase' ), 

    ))
```